# Update textview on android

Tags: android

the problem is that my layout is to type on and I need a `TextView` move from one party to an 'other screen, to do this I make sure that the layout view and then remove all face appear again the same `TextView` in such a way as not to have that the `TextView` be "dragged" across the screen.

Here's my code:

```
Textview textview = new TextView(context); //context was been defined

poiView.removeAllViews();
for (int j = 0; j < poiP.length; j++) {
    //code
    texview.setText("iojforj");

    poiView.addView(textview, params); //params was been defined
    textview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            function (v.getId());
        }
    });
```

Now the problem is that the `TextView` seems, it works, moves and so on but will not let me access the method Mr clicks because the `TextView` is removed and put in the time.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do and what doesn't work. What is the question here? This is your first post, don't get negative rep.

Comment: in practice since the TextView is added and removed forever, when I click on the TextView, I do not access the onclick method

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing and re-adding the textView, you should just mess with it's visibility.

So instead of removing them and adding them later on, you should just do

```
textView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); //to make it disappear
textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); //to make it reappear
```

that way they will keep their assigned OnClickListeners

however if this is running from a different thread, you need to put this in a `runOnUiThread()` call.

EDIT:
lets try this

```
  Textview textview = new TextView(context); //context has been defined
  poiView.removeAllViews();
  OnClickListener buttonListener = new OnClickListener() { //listener here }
  for (int j = 0; j < poiP.length; j++) 
  {
    //code
    texview.setText("iojforj");

    poiView.addView(textview, params); //params was been defined
    textview.setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
  }
```

Comment: i use a method compass in this apk so when i rotate a device, my textview change position, and i want that textview don't leave trace of position and i have doing removeallview and after add view

Comment: @danielefiscolo So why didn't you say so 4 hours ago in the opening post?

Comment: define a const onClickListener somewhere, then just reassign the same onClick when you re-add the textview... it's ugly, but it might work.

Comment: oh well, we gave it a shot. we should definately wait for someone to give us a working solution instead of trying out things for ourselves.

Comment: but exist a method that i can freeze for one moment a textview on screen??